# SonarQube Exception with .net framework application on ubuntu

Tags: c#, .net, ubuntu, jenkins, sonarqube

I have Jenkins and SonarQube setup on different server(**Ubuntu**).
I am building a .net framework application on Jenkins using **Mono**.

The Application is successfully built.

I am trying to scan and generate a report of the project using SonarQube.Configured SonarQube on Ubuntu server and Integrated with Jenkins.

Installed C# Plugin and FxCops plugin on SonarQube.
Here is Jenkins Configuration with SonarQube:-

Execute SonarQube Scanner
`sonar.host.url= http://*****:9000`
`sonar.projectKey=ShopApp`
`sonar.projectVersion = 4.6.1`
`sonar.sources= /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ShopApp/`
sonar.language= cs

But I am facing the following:

> WARNING: Property missing: 'sonar.cs.analyzer.projectOutPaths'. No protobuf files will be loaded for this project.
>
> WARNING : No roslyn issues report not found for this project**

SonarQube unable to scan C# . Please help me!

Comment: Are you using Scanner CLI or Scanner for MSBuild?

Comment: Scanner CLI. I have configured MSBuild path **/usr/lib/mono/4.5/xbuild.exe** in Global Configuration Jenkins.

Comment: According to [this issue](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-csharp/issues/1034) Scanner CLI doesn't directly support .NET projects. I believe you can use Scanner for MSBuild with mono as was described [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild).

Comment: Getting Error :- **SonarScanner for MSBuild executable was not found for mono** I have configured Mono use for xbuild.exe in Global configuration of Jenkins  
 for SonarScanner for MSBuild   :--  /usr/lib/mono/4.5/xbuild.exe....  Does xbuild will work for MSBuild?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't help you with that. What I would do though is first try to run analysis using command line (without Jenkins). If that doesn't work, then you can be sure that it's something not related to Jenkins.

Comment: I tried manually using cmd in windows to analysis report that worked in local system , but Once I am trying using Jenkins integration, Scanner for MSBuild failed there too.     For Linux for same issue..., I thought like have some configuration issue of SonarQube with jenkins for C# application in Linux. What should I do .?

Comment: Have you tried running sonarqube analysis using [Jenkins Pipeline](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-AnalyzinginaJenkinspipeline)? You have control over what is being passed to sonar scanner. Check out the script under "SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild".

Comment: Analysis on non-Windows platforms is supported only through the `dotnet` command. You should be able to run the Scanner for MSBuild executable (e.g. the Windows `.exe` file) with Mono and get results, though. In any case you have to use Scanner for MSBuild to analyze .NET code. Scanner CLI will not work.

Comment: unable to build dotnet application even,Installed Dotnet core in Ubuntu machine from this link https://dev.to/carlos487/installing-dotnet-core-in-ubuntu-1804-7lp and configured MSBuild.dll in Jenkins Global Configuration and configured Scanner for MSBuild to analyze .NET Core Application in Jenkins:-*dotnet usr/lib/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll begin /k:"CoreApp" /n:"CoreApp"
dotnet build eShopOnWeb.sln
dotnet /usr/lib/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll end ** but got below error **Unable to read the SonarQube analysis settings file '/usr/lib/SonarQube.Analysis.xml'.Please fix the content of this file**.

Comment: installed SonarQube on different VM and able to access it,have tried with 2 option for SonarScanner for MSBuild in Jenkins.1st installed **.NET Core2.0 sonarscanner for msbuild**and edited SonarQube.Analysis.xml A/C to sonar configuration.2nd have used Automatically installation of **SonarScanner for msbuild netcore2.0 inJenkins**,but got same error even.Please give me exact solution.